# how to parse すごい綺麗 (連続の形容詞と形容動詞の活用について)

Tags: i-adjectives

## Japanese

標準語か方言か独自の喋り方かわからないのですが、僕の友達はこのようによく話します：

> すごい綺麗な景色

この文に対して気になるのは、なぜ「すごい」は形容詞の活用になっているのでしょうか。

形容詞を連続する場合、「すごく、綺麗な」のようにするのが標準語だと思っていました。また、副詞の場合「すごく綺麗な」のようにするのが普通だと思っていました。

上述のように言うのは普通ですか。僕はどこか勘違いしているのでしょうか。

## English

I don't know if this is standard Japanese, a dialect, or an idiolect, but one of my friends often speaks in the following way:

> すごい綺麗な景色

What interests me here is the "すごい" which is being conjugated as an adjective, right?

I thought when you have two adjectives next to each other (I guess more precisely here a 形容詞 and 形容動詞) that the adjectival conjugation would be すごく、綺麗な and the adverbial would be the すごく綺麗な.

Is the above version correct? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: 参考になるかも: [「近現代日本語における新語・新用法の研究」研究発表会　概要 | 国立国語研究所](https://www.ninjal.ac.jp/event/specialists/project-meeting/pm-report/20120828-025re/) , [#997. ''real bad'' と「すごいヤバい」](http://user.keio.ac.jp/~rhotta/hellog/2012-01-19-1.html)

Comment: ちなみに、使われてる方は女性です。（参考になるものと同じ傾向）

Comment: @Yosh それがそのまま答えな気がします

Comment: @broccoliforest 文章にまとめるのを面倒がってサボってしまいました…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%87%84%E3%81%8F-302309)によりますと：

> 〔近年，くだけた言い方で「すごく」の代わりに「すごいでっかい」「すごいきれいだ」などと言う場合があるが，標準的でないとされる〕

とありますように、比較的新しい使い方で、口語的・俗語的なものだと思います。書き言葉やきちんとした会話においては、「すごく」あるいは「とても」「たいへん」「非常に」などが使われると思いますが（「すごく」も、「大変」などより口語的とされます）、くだけた会話においてはかなり広く「すごい」が副詞的に使われていると思います。したがって、

> すご**い**綺麗な景色

といった表現は、本来は「すご**く**綺麗な景色」のように言うべきものですが、くだけた会話ではよく使われていると思います。